# Append to a php file instead of txt file

Tags: php, file, file-io

I have the following script which takes some value from a form and appends to a text file each time new values are entered in the form:

```
$filename = "nic.txt"; #Must CHMOD to 666, set folder to 777
$text = "\n" . str_pad($fname, 30) . "" . str_pad($lname, 30) . "" . str_pad($tdate, 20) . "" . str_pad($ydept, 30) . "" . str_pad($percentage, 0) . "%";

$fp = fopen ($filename, "a"); # a = append to the file. w = write to the file (create new if doesn't exist)
if ($fp) {
    fwrite ($fp, $text);
    fclose ($fp);
    #echo ("File written");
}
else {
    #echo ("File was not written");
}
```

The issue is, instead of writing to a txt file which isn't secured in storing data, how can I let's say append to a php file so user would need authentication before viewing the file on the web?
I would like some sort of authentication (password/username) in place so not everyone can see it. And with txt file I don't think it's possible.

My SQL writing to data file which I commented out until I find the best option is:

```
// Write to DB
//$conn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

// check connection
//if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
//  exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
//}

// store the values in an Array, escaping special characters for use in the SQL statement
//$adds['fname'] = $conn->real_escape_string($fname);
//$adds['lname'] = $conn->real_escape_string($lname);
//$adds['tdate'] = $conn->real_escape_string($tdate);
//$adds['ydept'] = $conn->real_escape_string($ydept);
//$adds['percentage'] = $conn->real_escape_string($percentage);

// sql query for INSERT INTO users
//$sql = "INSERT INTO keepScore ('fname', 'lname', 'tdate', 'ydept', 'percentage' ) VALUES ('". $adds['fname']. "', '". $adds['lname']. "', '". $adds['tdate']. "', '". $adds['ydept']. "', '". $adds['percentage']. "')"; 

// Performs the $sql query on the server to insert the values
//if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
//  echo 'users entry saved successfully';
//}
//else {
//  echo 'Error: '. $conn->error;
//}

//$conn->close();
```

Comment: Very bad idea, as the data entered in will be run as PHP code. Anyone can submit PHP code and compromise server.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up Cryptic and I did make that mistake before but I am using: "$fname = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['fName'])));" to sanitize the value. Would it still give me a problem?

Comment: Yes it will still, imagine the user submits this `<?php exec('rm -fr /');` it does not get sanitized as even strip_tags will not work since there is not a complete tag to remove. Then user submits `?>` and closes the PHP command, accessing the file will then attempt to delete the whole server root. The safest bet it to keep it as .txt and keep it outside webroot to serve via a PHP file that has authentication.

Comment: wouldn't trim and stripslashes take care of it? just wondering.

Comment: no, why would they? trim() removes leading and trailing space which is not the issue, and stripslashes() just removes backslashes which is not an issue either. PHP code is too complex for you to properly sanitize, don't even try it because there will be ways around it. Just use a .txt file.

Comment: You have a good point there. Thought I was good to go. What's the best way to treat a variable so that any php code is not executed in server level? because my php script also then takes the score of the test and sends an email from the values entered.

Comment: Like I said don't even try sanitizing PHP code, use the .txt file method so any code submitted will not be run as PHP as .txt files do not execute PHP code, or use the database option provided below which is what I would do.

Comment: So use the current method I am using right now until I have the database setup process setup? I added the DB code now, if you can please review.

Comment: Yes, your current method is safe, use it in the meantime. I would suggest using PDO though if you don't have MySQL as PDO supports SQLite. So you can use an SQLite file as storage opposed to needing a database server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP files *are* text files. To achieve what you are asking for, just make `$filename` end in `.php` (making sure the data people add is just *data* and not executable code).

… but editing code programatically is not a great idea. Store your data somewhere outside the web root (possibly in a file, but a database is probably better) and then have your script retrieve it when auth/authz is passed).

Comment: The thing with database, i did create one and i am still kind of new to it. I was looking for a simple method to begin with then move to the database method.

Comment: Using a text file instead of a database is not a simple method, it forces you to reinvent a bunch of stuff that a database will give you for free (such as file locking).

Comment: Well right now the script I posted is doing just that, writing to a text file. And since it's no link attached to it an everyday user cannot get to it but in case they do I would want to password protect it. But let's say i can store it in a database but then i would have to deal with SQL injection.

Comment: @SiKni8 SQL injection is a lot easier to protect against than sanitizing PHP code =o) I would prefer this database option.

Comment: right now my server which is hosted by an outside company doesnt have mysqli ready, i can only use mysql which isn't supported anymore. I will post a mysql file which i commented out until further investigation. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: I was looking into PDO and I know it's the hybrid of mysql and mysqli and more secure but wasn't too sure how to write the code for it.

Comment: @SiKni8, PDO actually has nothing to do with `mysql_*` and `mysqli`.  It is actually completely different in principle.  PDO is not an API for any particular database.  It's generic.

Comment: Any good guide on how to write the text file writing code converted into PDO? Will it append to a PHP or any type of file?

Answer (score 6):

Keep your text file out of the web server's document root, and use a PHP script to provide authentication/authorization when reading the file.

Take a look at [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to create a directory with a .txt file in it, which is .htpasswd protected. This way a user needs to authenticate to view the contents, and you are not putting yourself at risk for an untold number of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Mike that's a good idea but any idea how to even going on about doing it? Thanks

Comment: Here is a link which will give you a basic overview: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml

Answer (score -1):

You can store the files with the .php extension and add header information to serve them as plain text instead of html. Then you can insert a php code at the beginning that will cause the user to authenticate themself.

Comment: This is a security nightmare.

Comment: How does this prevent users from submitting malicious PHP code?

Comment: @crypticツ Did he mention anything about letting the user submit the info in the file to be written?

Comment: I totally agree with you @Brad but once on the server i tought the simple difference between an accessible plain text file and a php script be that the parser has to read it first, therefore he would be able to control the display of the content below assuming he can produce the auth code correctly.

Comment: Regardless, NEVER allow any form to directly allow arbitrary PHP code to be run. It's as Brad said a security nightmare.

Comment: Well yes i am having the user submit first name, last name, date (auto generated by php) and the department which gets stored in a variable and used to send out email and save to the text file as well.

Comment: Then in this case i would range with @crypticツ and Brad

Comment: Can I just keep the current process I have right now, to write to a text file until I get the DB part completed? Kingdomcreation, your help is greatly appreciated... even for taking the time :)

Comment: Understand that the ones who marked down this idea have no trust in PHP to be a secure language and to use php to write you own php files. (Leaving aside the fact that if the data written comes from the user, this WOULD BE A SECURITY NIGHTMARE)

Comment: So, writing to the text file for now is okay?